# NSPredicate Filter Through Array Of Objects

Tags: ios, xcode, nspredicate, predicate

This is my custom NSObject Class:

```
@interface personObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *personName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage *personPhoto;

@property BOOL invited;

- (id) initWithName: (NSString *) personName Photo: (UIImage *) photo Invited: (BOOL *) invited;

@end

@implementation personObject
@synthesize personName = _personName;
@synthesize personPhoto = _personPhoto;
@synthesize invited = _invited;

 - (id) initWithName:(NSString *)personName Photo:(UIImage *)photo Invited:(BOOL *)invited{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.personName = personName;
        self.personPhoto = photo;
        self.invited = invited;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I init three person Objects in the viewDidLoad.
Now I tried

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"personName beginswith[c], searchText];
```

But i get an ERROR --

```
-[personObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109684330'
```

So I tried This:

```
- (void) filterContententForSearchText: (NSString *) searchText scope:(NSString *) scope{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K beginsWith[c]  %@",_currentPerson.personName, searchText ];
    self.searchArray = [self.peopleArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
```

So i tried setting

```
_currentPerson  = [self.peopleArray objectAtIndex.row];
```

in the tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath method and used this instead. But i get a different ERROR -- reason:

```
'[<personObject 0x109524750> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Paul Smith.'
```

Both these errors happen when I begin to type into the search bar.

Heres the row method...How do you set the cell text to currentPerson.personName in the search array

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    personObject *currentPerson = [self.peopleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    self.personCell = (personCell *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"personCell"];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        self.personCell.nameLabel.text = [self.searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else{
        self.personCell.nameLabel.text = currentPerson.personName;
    }
    return _personCell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `personName` key not `_currentPerson.personName` as key.When you are giving the `_currentPerson.personName` it take as it key and think about it as whole key which should be `NSCoding`compliant.But you do not need it you can pass only `@"personName"` as string and it will work through `keyValueCoding`.Replace above function with below

```
- (void) filterContententForSearchText: (NSString *) searchText scope:(NSString *) scope{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K beginsWith[c]  %@",@"personName", searchText ];
   self.searchArray = [self.peopleArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"%@",seachArray);
}
```

Comment: still get an error---- reason: '-[personObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1097316a0'

Comment: .It is executing fine i have checked.You also do not need BOOL *just use BOOL.`- (id) initWithName: (NSString *) personName Photo: (UIImage *) photo Invited: (BOOL) invited;`

Comment: may be you are doing something more.On which line it is crashing

Comment: oh... the problem was with displaying the search content...So that worked but how do you set the label cell text to the personName in the PersonObject in the array.